# Hide original when cloning element in SVG

Tags: svg

I'm generating an SVG where I want to use an element as a stamp to create many similar elements.

This works well using `<rect>` and `<use>`, with one caveat:
I want to hide my "tool" element (the original `<rect>`). How can I do this in SVG?

This is what my current SVG looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect id="blocked" width="20" height="20" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" />
<use href="#blocked" x="20" y="100" />
<use href="#blocked" x="60" y="60" />
<use href="#blocked" x="60" y="100" />
</svg>
```

[image]

Here is a workaround, where I move the `<rect>` outside the viewbox, but then I have to compensate in the coordinates for the `<use>` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect id="blocked" width="20" height="20" x="-1000" y="-1000" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" />
<use href="#blocked" x="1020" y="1100" />
<use href="#blocked" x="1060" y="1060" />
<use href="#blocked" x="1060" y="1100" />
</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the original element a child of `<defs>`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <rect id="blocked" width="20" height="20" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" />
</defs>
<use href="#blocked" x="20" y="100" />
<use href="#blocked" x="60" y="60" />
<use href="#blocked" x="60" y="100" />
</svg>
```